# How to mark some columns as ignored for calculations Numbers?

Tags: numbers, iwork

I'm creating a template on Numbers and I would like to know if there is a way for the formula to ignore, or skip over some cells or even entire columns. I need these columns for some calculations, but need them to be overlooked for others. The catch being, which column will have to be skipped over will be different every time.

Maybe there is a way to "mark" a column to be ignored, with the help of a checkbox, perhaps?

Or is there an even easier, more obvious way that has eluded me?

Comment: Could you please add an example? Right now I don't really understand why you can't simply point the formule to the cells you do want included in a calculation.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As I said, the columns to skip won't be the same from one user to the next, or from one month to the next... It may be cells in columns B, D and G this time or cells in column A next time.

Comment: Ah ok. So a cell should calculate `A1+B1+C1+D1` for one month, and when in another month the *same* cell should calculate `A1+D1`, right? If it's actually based on months you could try writing a (nested) [if-then-else condition](http://help.apple.com/functions/mac/5.0/#ffa5834118).

Comment: Thanks, that does seem to be the general direction I want to go. However the difficulty is that the users will be the ones picking the column in which the cells to be ignored live...

Comment: Hmm... There are [checkmarks](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH14836) which translate to a `1` or `0` value. You could incorporate that value in your formule. Using my previous example, assuming checkmarks live in the first row and data lives in the second row onwards you could try something like `A$1*A2+B$1*B2+C$1*C2+D$1*D2`.

Comment: That looks like exactly what I'm trying to do, thanks a million! I'll try that tonight and let you know. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

In practice, you could sum each column and then sum just the the sum row.

That way, you can delete the sum of the column to be skipped when needed and it should be clear about which of the columns is ignored.

A more general solution will be tricky since it's programming in conditional values or conditional functions that are much harder to maintain, debug and be confident your math is correct as you use the tool over time.